# Why double slashes front of JSON String

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a JSON string from google, which i can not use it because of the double slashes in front of the JSON string, it returns JSON exception.

How can i escape them before parse?

> https://www.google.com/finance/info?q=asels
>
> // [ { "id": "530630671033488" ,"t" : "ASELS" ,"e" : "IST" ,"l" :
>   "13.72" ,"l_fix" : "13.72" ,"l_cur" : "TRY13.72" ,"s": "0"
>   ,"ltt":"6:10PM GMT+3" ,"lt" : "Jan 20, 6:10PM GMT+3" ,"lt_dts" :
>   "2017-01-20T18:10:00Z" ,"c" : "+0.04" ,"c_fix" : "0.04" ,"cp" : "0.29"
>   ,"cp_fix" : "0.29" ,"ccol" : "chg" ,"pcls_fix" : "13.68" } ]

Comment: ...remove the slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the two double slashes in beginning, then you have a regular JSON String that you can parse.

You can do it like this:

```
String yourJsonStringFromGoogle = ...
fixedJsonString = yourJsonStringFromGoogle.substring(2);
```

Here, `substring(n)` removes n letters from the beginning of the string.